# Create master checkbox outside {foreach} tag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have **dynamic page** under `{foreach}` tag something like this.

```
<div id="c1">
{foreach}
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="{$num}" checked/>
{/foreach}
</div>
```

which in return **prints** something like this.

```
<div id="c1">
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="1" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="2" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="3" checked/>
</div>
```

What I want is to **hide** `<div id="c1">` & **show only one checkbox outside** 
    `<div id="c1">`

**controlling all checkboxes which are inside** `<div id="c1">`

How can I achieve this ?

**Thanks.**

- Mandar

Comment: why do you want to hide them then control???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/3Hjam/ *(click the checkbox in the right panel)*

HTML

```
<div id="c1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="1" checked />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="2" checked />
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="3" checked />
</div>
<input type="checkbox" name="master" id="master" checked />
```

​

jQuery

```
$('#c1').hide();

$('#master').change(function() {
        // Click the children of c1 when the master is clicked
    $('#c1').children().click();

        // Display the current values in an alert
    var result = $('#c1').children().map(function() {
        return $(this).attr('checked');
    }).get().join(',');

    alert(result);
});
```